# filter data frame based on boolean of index value

Tags: python, pandas

new to pandas and I think I'm missing something really basic about dataframes.

```
e=pd.DataFrame(data={'a':[1,1,2,2,3,3],'b':[7,8,9,10,11,12],'c':[20,21,22,23,24,25]}).set_index(['a','c'])
```

how would I filter this dataframe based on the index `a` being greater than 2?

```
e.query('"a" > 2')
```

gives me

```
'>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'
```

Comment: If you get rid of the index setting you could just do: `e[e['a'] > 2]`

Comment: Try e[e.index.get_level_values(0) > 2] or e.query('a > 2')

Comment: The other question doesn't address using a boolean, which is where I was getting tripped up. most answers on SO use a list of values to filter the index.

Comment: This is what I needed: `e.query('a > 2')` I've been working on this too long and didn't spot the ". i actually had just figured that out myself, but time to go home i think